# Vue/Nuxt persist variable within session

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, nuxt.js

I'm currently using Google Maps Javascript API to instantiate a map object. I have a simple map page. The issue is that I realized when I navigate across pages (routes), and then back to the map page, I re-instantiate the map object which seems unnecessary to me (counting as another API call). In vanillaJS I'll just be creating a global map variable.

I am wondering what I could do if I want to persist the map object within the session so that routing back and forth calls back the same map object.

My code looks somewhat like this...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
methods: {
    onScriptLoaded() {
      console.log("Triggered Maps API");
      this.map = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(somelat, somelng),
        zoom: 11,
        ...})
    }

mounted(){
if (!process.server && !window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.onload = this.onScriptLoaded;
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API KEY>&libraries=places";
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    } else {
      this.onScriptLoaded();
    }
}
</script>
```

When I return from a route (eg. /about), `this.map` becomes undefined and is instantiated again.

Is there any way to persist the `this.map` object such that it still holds the map object when I return to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use vue-router, you could cache the routed components with keep-alive.

```
  <keep-alive>
    <router-view />
  </keep-alive>
```

This will cache all routes. If you want to cache only the target component, use include:

```
  <keep-alive :include=['mapComponent']>
    <router-view />
  </keep-alive>
```

NOTE: 'mapComponent' is the name of your component, not the the name of your route.

Or, you could chache the component directly:

```
<keep-alive>
  <map-component></map-component>
</keep-alive>
```

With `keep-alive`, the mounted hook will be called once, after component creation. To trigger any specific action when navigating to or from the route, you will use `activated()` and `deactivated()` hooks.

Comment: I'm looking to cache the `map` object for all routes, which is probably your first suggestion. How would I use `keep-alive` in the context of NuxtJS?

Comment: use the first option in my answer: wrap `<router-view/>` with `keep-alive` tags. this will cache all routes

Comment: I am unable to find a `<router-view/>` in my Nuxt setup, how should i go about doing that?

Comment: for Nuxt, keep-alive option is passed as a property to <nuxt />: <nuxt keep-alive />

Comment: hmm, is this referring to my default.vue in layouts?

Comment: exactly. `<nuxt />` in default.vue is the entry point for all your components. is an analog of `router-view`, in `vue-router`.